# How to interpret SEM mediation analysis results (using Lavaan in R) with binary exposure and outcome variables

Tags: r, binary, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I have built SEM model in R using Lavaan. My aim is to report on the indirect effect.

The data I am using is confidential, so I will not be able to share it or provide a reproducible example. Since I am **focused on the interpretation of the results**, I don't think a reproducible example will be necessary. I will also provide some code and hypothetical results for simplicity.

To give some background, I am interested in the effect of two strains of a virus on severity (hospitalisation). And I am interested in how SES (income and education) mediates this relationship. I created a latent variable based on income and education. The part which makes this tricky for me to understand is that both my exposure (variant -> 1 = variant 1, 0 = variant 2) and outcome (hospitlaisation -> 1 = hosp, 0 = not hosp) are binary. SES variables are quintiles (Q1 = most educated / highest income) which were coded as numeric to work with Lavaan. All the examples I see online use numeric variables.

Code below:

```
library(tidyverse, lavaan)

full_model <- ' 
                latent_ses =~ income_q + educ_q
              
                status_hosp ~ a1*variant + b1*latent_ses + age + sex_Male + vaccination + comorbidities
                latent_ses ~  c1*variant 
                
                direct_modl := a1
                ses_modl := b1
                indirect_modl := c1*b1 
                total_model := a1 + c1*b1 
                '

model.fit1_full <- sem(full_model, data= d_o,  ordered="status_hosp")

parameter_est <- parameterEstimates(model.fit1_full, ci = TRUE, level = 0.95, boot.ci.type = 'perc') %>%    
   select(label, est, se, pvalue, ci.lower, ci.upper) %>%     
   filter(label == 'indirect_modl' |label == 'direct_modl' | label == 'ses_modl' | label == 'total_model') 

fit_meas <- fitMeasures(model.fit1_full, c("cfi", 'tli', 'rmsea', "srmr")) %>%   
   as.data.frame() %>% t()
```

Let's assume measures of fit(cfi, tli, rmsea, srmr) all appear to be good and latent variable loads well. Some hypothetical results are presented below. I will provide two hypothetical model representing scenarios where the direct effect and indirect effect are of same sign (direction) and of different.

```
    Hypothetical result #1 
        > parameter_estimate

                  label    est    se   pvalue 
        1   direct_modl  -0.50   0.05      0 
        2      ses_modl   0.25   0.04      0 
        3 indirect_modl  -0.12   0.01      0  
        4   total_model  -0.62   0.05      0  
        

    Hypothetical result #2   
        > parameter_estimate

                  label    est    se   pvalue 
        1   direct_modl  -0.50    0.05     0 
        2      ses_modl   0.29    0.04     0 
        3 indirect_modl   0.10    0.01     0  
        4   total_model  -0.40    0.05     0
```

My questions are:

1. How can I **interpret these results** (specifically the indirect effect!) given that the **outcome and exposure variables are binary**.
2. Is it right to be **exponentiating the estimates given the outcome is binary** (as with logistic model)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The question above is more conceptual/methodological, and not code-related. So, it is not so likely to get good answers here (can even be considered out of topic). The best place to ask is not SO, but Cross-Validated StackExchange (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But, in short, the question above needs to start with a discussion on choosing the most suited estimators (see, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/sem-with-binary-dependent-variable)

Comment: Hi hamagust, thanks for your reply! I have re-posted this question to Cross-Validated StackExchange, I do agree, it does seem like a much better forum. As for your other point, I agree, I think it is something I need to look into more. I was hoping to try to understanding the meaning of the coefficient and then try to work through which estiator would be best. I think when using "ordered="status_hosp" in your sem call, that it automatically selects the most suited estimator for a binary variable.

Comment: For my Cross-Validated StackExchange, link see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577879/how-to-interpret-sem-mediation-analysis-results-using-lavaan-in-r-with-binary